# Sorting Number Strings Using Lodash and React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, lodash, semantic-ui

I'm working to sort my table columns.  My column with text is sorting fine, yet the ones with numbers are not.

When i examine the data with the numbers I'm trying to sort I see the following.  This is just one example:

```
watchCount: ["2"]
```

In addition, some items don't have some of fields I need, and in that case I am just displaying a 0. Can see that below.

This is my table where I am mapping over the data. I also just tried to include a parseInt() with the numerical data, but that is not helping.  I'm trying to replicate this example: [semantic ui react sort](https://react.semantic-ui.com/collections/table/#variations-sortable)

I just can't tell if i'm doing something wrong with my sorting here, or if this just won't sort because it's a string.

```
 <Table sortable celled fixed striped>
          <Table.Header>
            <Table.Row>
              <Table.HeaderCell
                sorted={column === "title" ? direction : null}
                onClick={() => handleSort("title")}
              >
                Card Title
              </Table.HeaderCell>
              <Table.HeaderCell
                sorted={column === "bids" ? direction : null}
                onClick={() => handleSort("bids")}
              >
                # Bids
              </Table.HeaderCell>
              <Table.HeaderCell
                sorted={column === "watch" ? direction : null}
                onClick={() => handleSort("watch")}
              >
                Watchers
              </Table.HeaderCell>
              <Table.HeaderCell
                sorted={column === "price" ? direction : null}
                onClick={() => handleSort("price")}
              >
                Price
              </Table.HeaderCell>
              <Table.HeaderCell
                sorted={column === "time" ? direction : null}
                onClick={() => handleSort("time")}
              >
                Time Left
              </Table.HeaderCell>
            </Table.Row>
          </Table.Header>
          <Table.Body>
            {_.map(filteredData, card => (
              <>
                <Table.Row key={card.id}>
                  <Table.Cell>{card.title}</Table.Cell>
                  <Table.Cell>
                    {parseInt(
                      card.sellingStatus[0].bidCount
                        ? card.sellingStatus[0].bidCount
                        : 0
                    )}
                  </Table.Cell>
                  <Table.Cell>
                    {parseInt(
                      card.listingInfo[0].watchCount
                        ? card.listingInfo[0].watchCount
                        : 0
                    )}
                  </Table.Cell>
                  <Table.Cell>
                    $
                    {parseInt(
                      card.sellingStatus &&
                        card.sellingStatus[0].currentPrice[0]["__value__"]
                    )}
                  </Table.Cell>
                  <Table.Cell>
                    <TimeAgo
                      date={new Date(
                        card.listingInfo && card.listingInfo[0].endTime
                      ).toLocaleDateString()}
                    />
                  </Table.Cell>
                </Table.Row>
              </>
            ))}
          </Table.Body>
        </Table>
```

Note, here is also my handleSort function

```
 const [column, setColumn] = useState(null);
  const [direction, setDirection] = useState(null);
  const [filteredData, setData] = useState(props.cardsToShow);

  console.log("CARDS TO SHOW", props.cardsToShow);
  console.log("TYPE OF", typeof cardsToShow);
  console.log("Filtered Data", filteredData);
  console.log("column", column);
  console.log("direction", direction);

  const handleSort = clickedColumn => {
    if (column !== clickedColumn) {
      setColumn(clickedColumn);
      setData(_.sortBy(filteredData, [clickedColumn]));
      setDirection("ascending");
      return;
    }

    setData(_.sortBy(filteredData.reverse()));
    direction === "ascending"
      ? setDirection("descending")
      : setDirection("ascending");
  };
```

EDITED CODE

```
const handleSortNumeric = clickedColumn => {
    const sorter = data => ~~data[clickedColumn];
    setData(_.sortBy(filteredData, sorter));
  };

  const handleSortReverse = () => {
    const sorter = data => ~~data;
    setData(_.sortBy(filteredData.reverse(), sorter));
  };

  const handleSort = clickedColumn => {
    if (column !== clickedColumn) {
      setColumn(clickedColumn);
      // setData(_.sortBy(filteredData, [clickedColumn]));
      handleSortNumeric(clickedColumn);
      setDirection("ascending");
      return;
    }

    // setData(_.sortBy(filteredData.reverse()));
    handleSortReverse();
    direction === "ascending"
      ? setDirection("descending")
      : setDirection("ascending");
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorting strings will follow the Unicode ordering and they happen per character instead of as a whole with a number.  So when sorting "40" and "5" you would expect "5" to come first but the "4" in "40" is what it compares with and loses.

See here for more details:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

As far as fixing your issue directly, you can pass the `_.sortBy()` a function as the second argument instead and in the function convert the values to numbers (using `~~`, `Number()`, `parseInt()`, etc) to avoid a string comparison.

Since you seem to have these hard-coded you could also use a separate handleSort func to separate the concerns:

```
const handleSortNumeric = ( clickedColumn ) => {
    // ...

    const sorter = data => ~~data[ clickedColumn ];
    setData(_.sortBy(filteredData, sorter));

    // ...
};
```

---

But if you have control over how the data is presented from the server, you should provide it properly typed to avoid things like this in the future

Comment: thanks Deryck, this makes a lot of sense.  i tried your suggestion and I'm posting my code above--wondering if you see any issues with what i'm doing--as it's not workin for some reason.

Comment: yeah your `handleSortReverse()` is just doing `~~data` instead of `~~data[clickedColumn]`.  Since `data` is going to be an object this will just turn into `0` every time.  Also you don't need to do `_.sortBy()` if you just want to reverse the outcome - you already have `.reverse` and can just leave it at that - `setData(filteredData.reverse())`